# How to design the server side of an autocomplete box like Quora?

Tags: java, autocomplete, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

I don't want to use Lucene because i think it is to **heavy**.

Is there any easier way to implement this (Millons of data) ?

Comment: I don't really know Quora well enough to be able to answer - is it just an autocomplete box like there are on lots of other websites (such as Google's) or is there something more special about it?

Comment: Well, just looks like Google's.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to worry about performance, I recommend you take a look at Amazon Web Services new CloudSearch service. It's fast and scales as your needs scale. It can also handle millions of documents without a problem and supports wildcard searches (ex: quo*, would retrieve Quora).

Check it out [here](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this isn't how it definitely works at either Quora or Google, as I haven't had the pleasure to work at either...this is just how I'd go about doing it.

The first thing to obtain is a list of search terms - I'm assuming you don't want to know how this is done, as it will really depend on all sorts of things, but basically you're either going to do a `select distinct title from pages` (in the case of the autocomplete on Wikipedia) or something much more advanced in the case of Google's.

The next step is also pretty simple at a high level: you need to perform the query `select title from titles where title like 'Qu%'` in the case of the user typing `Qu` into the search box. The list of titles is then returned to the browser as the response to some kind of Ajax request, perhaps in the form of JSON or similar. And you need to do it as fast as possible - that's where it becomes difficult.

How do they do it so quickly? There are probably four things to bear in mind.

1. They have LOTS of machines handling the requests. Bear in mind that Google's autocomplete is turned on by default and works in (almost?) all languages. That's a lot of searches against the autocomplete index. A lot more than there will be against the web index itself: for each web search request, Google will probably have processed 3 or 4 autocomplete requests.
2. They're probably doing it in memory. Google is already known to store its web indexes in memory, so I would expect them to be doing the same with this.
3. Specialised software (this is where it gets really interesting). While a traditional database or a NoSQL database could do this and do it quickly I would expect the big boys to actually be doing this with specialised code whose sole purpose is to provide autocomplete suggestions. The SQL statement I provided above was purely to demonstrate the logical request that would be needed. You're probably looking at some kind of specialised tree, such as a suffix tree, radix tree, or similar.
4. Sharding. To cope with the quantity of data and the number of machines doing the requests you're going to need to shard. That is ensure that a certain subset of all the machines involved only process requests requests that begin with one or more letters. eg a group of X machines processing searches that begin with a certain letter or even 2 letters. That means that you've got more machines, but they don't each have to have the whole index to hand. How does a particular group of machines get chosen? You're either routing once the request is in your data centre, or you could route on the client side (eg in your Javascript decide which IP to query based upon the first X letters of the search term)

So, that's how I would do it. Not having had the experience of the enormous datasets Google/Quora are dealing with, I'm sure there are things that I've not considered. But, it's a start.

And, here's how I have done it, purely in an experimental environment at home:

I had a simple list of a good few hundred thousand titles to search. These were loaded into a dedicated MongoDB collection, which had a single index defined on it. I then had a Play Framework controller in front of it and used jQuery's autocomplete plugin to do the search.

Obviously this is tiny compared with what you are looking for, but MongoDB should provide the same kind of performance for your dataset provided you follow the recommendations (ie good hardware, lots of RAM, keep the indexes in memory). In addition, Mongo supports sharding, and the Play Framework is shared nothing, so adding new machines to cope with the load should your userbase grow would be straightforward in this situation.

By the way, Mongo is by no means the only solution, traditional SQL databases will be up to the job too, of course - I was just using Mongo for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First, for autocomplete you should aim to get the response back to the user in <= 100ms if you want something that appears fast. That should be your first concern. Any setup that can't do that probably won't be good enough for users. In my own tests in Firefox using Firebug, Google's autocomplete returned returns in about 50ms and Quora in about 65ms.

See, e.g.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536300/what-is-the-shortest-perceivable-application-response-delay](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/powerful-autocomplete-with-redis-in-under-200-lines-of-python/)

Apparently, Quora uses prefix matching, not full text search which makes it faster. To roll your own fast prefix-based autocomplete, which should be sufficient for many cases, but won't handle things like misspellings using fuzzy matching, etc., try an in-memory data store like Redis. The details can be seen here:

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/powerful-autocomplete-with-redis-in-under-200-lines-of-python/

I haven't been able to get CloudSearch (95-125ms in browser fetching from endpoint directly as measured by Firebug, and + 20-30ms longer accessing endpoint via cURL in PHP) down to the low latencies of Google and Quora I cited regardless of the simplicity of the search query. An Elasticsearch cluster is a bit faster. These statements obviously depend upon use case and probably don't generalize well, but something to think about.